# How to use string operations within pandas eval function?

Tags: python, pandas, eval

If df is a data frame

```
data = {'Project':['1001', '1002', '1003', '1004'], 'Subject':['57001-01', '57001-02', '57001-03', '57001-04']} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

To add a new column, we can use

```
df["Subj_id"]=df["Project"]+"-"+df["Subject"].str[:5]
df
```

```
  Project Subject   Subj_id
0 1001    57001-01  1001-57001
1 1002    57001-02  1002-57001
2 1003    57001-03  1003-57001
3 1004    57001-04  1004-57001
```

But if I need to add this new column dynamically using df.eval(), I tried the following:

```
col_def='Subj_id = Project +"-"+ Subject.str[:5]'
df.eval('{0}'.format(col_def), inplace = True,engine='python')
```

but it gave the following error:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

How can I use the string operations within eval?

Comment: in your `col_def` line, if  you space it out a bit, you've got `"Subj_id = Project +" **-** "+ Subject.str[:5]"` so you've got your `"`s or `+`s in the wrong places...

Comment: It was a mistake in the question.  I corrected it:         I should've used single quote                                  :  col_def='Subj_id = Project +"-"+ Subject.str[:5]'

Comment: Define a function and pass it to df.apply() if it needs to be dynamic.  You are trying to use the most obscure approach to perform a common pandas operation.

Comment: The objective here is to add the new column based on the definition provided by the user.  In the above example, it is working perfectly fine, if I change the col_def as follws: ````col_def="Subj_id = Project +Subject"           
df.eval('{0}'.format(col_def), inplace = True,engine='python')```` .  This is not working when the col_def is with a concatenation or slicing operation